# Algebra with Sums In Mathematica

Tags: summation, algebra

I'm trying to perform basic algebra with summations and I haven't been able to find any information on whether it is possible in *Mathematica*.

For instance, I took this rule about multiplying sums from the *Mathematica* website (picture below) and tried to recreate it with this code

```
FullSimplify[Sum[Subscript[a,i],{i,0,n}]*Sum[Subscript[b,i],{i,0,n}]]
```

The output never looked like the right hand side of the equation (the expanded form of the product of sums).

Is this possible to do in *Mathematica*? I'm new and appreciate any help!

[image: summation formula]

Comment: Use replacement rules. For example, `Sum[Subscript[a, k], {k, 0, n}] * Sum[Subscript[b, j], {j, 0, n}]  /. Sum[expr1_, iter1_] * Sum[expr2_, iter2_]  :>  Sum[expr1 * expr2, iter1, iter2]`